# Can this strange implicit matrix equation be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra

### Question

Here's a question I wrote which I can't seem to find the answer to. Let $\hat A$ be an infinite dimensional matrix and $\hat 1$ be the identity operator in infinite dimensions.

$$ \hat A =   \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat 1 & \hat A  \\
    \hat 1 & \hat 1 
  \end{bmatrix}$$

In the equation above is an implicit equation $\hat A$  seems to define it. Is there any explicit equation in which $A$ is uniquely defined?

Answer (score 2):

"Infinite dimensions" needs a bit of care, there are different infinities. My example below is where the basis has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. I think it can be tweaked to provide an example where the basis is countable.

I think it is easier to deal with 
$$
\hat A =   \begin{bmatrix}
    \hat A & \hat 1  \\
    \hat 1 & \hat 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
but I think with a little care you can re-write it for the case you want.

Let $V$ be a real vector space with a basis indexed by the irrational numbers in $(0,1)$. That is, the basis is $\{e_x | 0<x<1, x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Order the basis by $e_{a}$ precedes $e_b$ if and only if $a<b$.

Now for each such $x$ there is a unique $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}<x<\frac{1}{2^n}$. We use these open intervals to to provide the blocks and sub-blocks and sub-sub-blocks (etc) implied by the recursive "definition" of $\hat A$.

Now let $T$ be the linear transformation defined by 
$$
T(e_x)= e_{x-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}+e_x+e_{2x}+\dots+e_{2^{n}}x\\\text{whenever       } x\in(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{1}{2^{n}}).
$$

I believe that the matrix of $T$ has the properties sought. The details are left to the reader.

Comment: Is there a general procedure of solving such types of matrix problems? Where can I read more about it? Thanks :D

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea! I am not even sure if the solution is unique.

Comment: When I think of this recursively (it seems intuitive to me) that in this case the solution should be unique. Sure one can construct examples like $A = A \otimes A $ which has many solutions such as $\pm \hat 1$

Comment: I find it difficult to root the recursion!