# Is this fractal equation complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, recreational-mathematics, fractals

### Background

I recently asked this question: [Can this strange implicit matrix equation be solved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977401/can-this-strange-implicit-matrix-equation-be-solved). Followed by [Is this "fractal equation" for fractals constructed by finite subdivision rules complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980212/is-this-fractal-equation-for-fractals-constructed-by-finite-subdivision-rules). However in the second question I realised I was imprecise and decided to think more carefully and ask a new question in the same spirit.

### Describing a fractal

Let us describe the mapping $T$

$$T:\hat A \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \hat A \\
R_{-\pi/3} \hat A \\
R_{\pi/3}\hat A  \\
 \hat A \\
\end{pmatrix} =\hat A_1
$$

$$T * T : \hat A \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \hat A_1 \\
R_{-\pi/3} \hat A_1  \\
R_{\pi/3}\hat A_1 \\
\hat A_1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \hat A_2
$$

Where $$R_\phi A_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 R_\phi \hat A \\
R_\phi R_{-\pi/3} \hat A  \\
R_\phi R_{\pi/3}\hat A  \\
 R_\phi \hat A \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Where $R_{\theta}$ is a rotation matrix that obeys: $R_{\theta} \cdot R_{\phi}  = R_{\theta+  \phi} $. Hence, upon infinitely applying $T$ and setting $\hat A$ to represent a vector, we have something that describes the below image:

[image]

Hence, we have a "fractal equation" for the above recursive picture. Also this gives one a very natural way to multiply fractals. For example:

We can define an operation:

$$ \hat A \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
 \hat 1 \\
R_{-\pi/3}   \\
R_{\pi/3}  \\
 \hat 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}   =  
\begin{pmatrix}
 \hat A \\
R_{-\pi/3} \hat A  \\
R_{\pi/3}\hat A  \\
 \hat A \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It's the same as outer product with the exception being the components of the matrix are matrices themselves.

$$ L: \hat B \to \hat B \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 
\hat 1 & \hat 1 \\
\hat 1 & \hat 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which can describe this when $B$ is set to be a square:

[image]

### Questions

Is this fractal equation complete (can it describe any [Finite subdivision rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal) fractals)? How would one go about proving this (if true?)?

Comment: If $A$ is a vector, and $TA$ is a matrix, then what is $TTA$ ? (If it's another matrix, what are the dimensions?)

Comment: I've edited the question to include $TT A $ I'm thinking of the matrix having its elements as matrices (rather than normal numbers) in that sense while the dimension of the matrix remains the same the dimension of it's elements does not .. .